# Is there a way in python to tail a file and work with the line-output

Tags: python

I am working on a short script which tails a logfile. it should be possible to filter the output with regex and split by /t if necessary.

I wrote something like this in perl some years ago but have to change it to python

perl-code-sniplet:

```
open(FILE,"tail -F logfile | grep -v something | ");
while(<FILE>){
    my @lineparts = split(/\t/,$_);
    ...
    do something else
    ...
}
```

I've already tried Popen different varieties (logger.sh contains tail -F on an remote server via ssh)

```
cmd = subprocess.Popen("./logger.sh").communicate()
for line in cmd.stdout.readline(): 
    test = line

    if re.match('.*ERR.*', test):
        print "ERROR"
```

But all I get is an output on stdout and I cannot manipulate it (never printed "ERROR")

Anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't help with the regex because you did not post an example of how the log file looks like. I can help with the tail of the file, since that's quite universal.

```
data = []
with open(logfile,'rt',encoding='utf-8')as infile:
    for i,e in enumerate(infile):
        data.append(e.strip())
    if i < 11:
        for line in data:
            print(line)
    else:
        for line in data[:-10]:
            print(line)
```

In your case you would save the "print" into a container and then run your regex against it.

Comment: thx, works like a charm

Comment: @PeterSander Would you consider up voting and accepting as answer. ^_^

Comment: my bad, forget to